# Android EditText exclude some leading characters

Tags: android, regex

In the class that extends EditText i have this following variable:

```
 private final String LEADING_ZERO_FILTER_REGEX = "^0+(?!$)";
```

This will make some input (leading character) autodeleted, however it can only handle zero(0),and symbols. And i am having 0.0 as an output sometimes(even this edit-able, it can be add 0.012313545 or something that lead with 0.0), this making my app ugly. **How to add 0.0 inside the regex?** I want to exclude 0.0, meaning in the EditText the input cannot be lead by 0.0 . FYI, my knowledge in regex is 0.1 from scale 1 to 10.

*note: my app calculate some values when the user input zero/anything that may make the result 0.0(zero point zero)

UPDATE info:
In the app there is 3 EditText 1st for price, 2nd for percentage and the 3rd for the result from them both. And i have custom edittext and it will make the input change to currency format(as the user typing) , this custom edittext have onChange and onCleared. On the onchange i put the calculation process and 1st,it will convert back the value to number format(there is also reverse function in the custom edittext) then calculate, however i am using Double.valueOf(the input from edittext) . That making the output also a in double format(it will converted to string 1st then put to the result edittext). I think the culprit is Double format which make the result 0.0 (actually is should have be empty(""),i dont know why it become 0.0(mistake havent found)).

**more note:
the edittext watch each other, lets say if the user input in the 1st and 2nd edittext the output will be the 3rd edittext. But if the user input into 1st and 3rd then the output will be on the 2nd(as percentage).

Comment: format it properly with sample input and output and your effort in making regex

Comment: i think you mean this `^(?:0(?:\.0)?)+`

Comment: @Avinash Raj when i make it to  "^(?:0(?:\.0)?)+(?!$)" it give an error Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )

Comment: oh, sorry do double escapes. `^(?:0(?:\\.0)?)+` or `^(?:0+|0\\.0)`and i don't know why you addded `(?!$)`

Comment: @all is there any recommended article or something that may increase my knowledge in regex?

Comment: @AvinashRaj (?!$) is for currency format, deleting the lead like $1,000 , i think or it is useless?

Comment: `(?!$)` won't delete the leading `$` symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the leading `0`'s or `0.0`, you could simply use the below regex.

```
 private final String LEADING_ZERO_FILTER_REGEX = "^(?:0\\.0|0+)";
```

Comment: shouldn't there be an $ to end the regex?

Comment: @JediFighter post a sample input along with expected output. Sample input must cover all the possibilities.

Comment: based on the update above, i have 3 edittext. If i input 1000 on 1st edittext and  0 on 2nd edittext the output should be 0. But the output is 0.0 , now it become .0  .I am making this in case the user delete the value from 2nd edittext and perhaps want to change it, the user will find this bug.

Comment: i think the problem comes from calculation algorithm

Comment: but do you know how to solve this? the 0.0 , .0 problem. The custom edittext make this LEADING_ZERO_FILTER_REGEX replace-able to any input given except the excluded values